# Calling ASP.Net Web Methods with Angular 2

Tags: c#, angular, webmethod

I seem to have a simple scenario but I can't get it to work...  I have an ASPX page with code behind.  I want to access the Web Methods in the code behind.  To do this I added a subscriber in my app.component.ts that calls the service which returns an observable.  The service should call my web method.  Here's my code:

service.component.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class GetDataService {
headers: any;
constructor(private _http: Http) {

}

WebMethodExample(): Observable<string> {
    return this._http.get("Default.aspx/WebMethodExample").map(
        (response: Response) => response.toString()
    );
}
}
```

app.component.ts (subscriber)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GetDataService } from './Components/service.component';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`,
providers:[GetDataService]
})
export class AppComponent {
name = 'Angular 2 (From component)';

constructor(private _get:GetDataService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("In OnInit"); 
    this._get.WebMethodExample().subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
}
}
```

Code behind (Default.aspx.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Web.Services;


namespace Angular2Demo10
{
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string WebMethodExample()
    {
        return "Sent from WebMethodExample";
    }
}
}
```

When I run this, I get the following in the console: "Response with status: 200 OK for URL: null".  I'm not sure why it isn't getting the URL.  Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:  Dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~2.1.1",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.1.1",
"@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
"@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
"@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.1",
"@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
"@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.1",
"bootstrap": "3.3.7",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"es5-shim": "^4.5.9",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.3",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
"rxjs": "5.4.3",
"systemjs": "0.19.39",
"zone.js": "^0.6.25"
```

},

Comment: This is unrelated but you can put WebMethods in `.asmx` Web Service files instead of in the actual forms.

Comment: Do you have your url folder structure in the right format? is there any routing that you've forgotten?

Comment: @Ric Im not sure I understand your question.  I can tell you about my file structures.  My Default.aspx is in the root directory.  The service.component.ts is in app/components.  Does this answer it?

Comment: @Marie Yeah, I'm aware, but this is not the preferred method.

Comment: I guess I had just assumed it was. When we used WebMethods on the actual form pages it caused all lifecycle events to fire which led to a lot of database loads and rendering for every call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at all the other examples, have you tried setting the headers correctly, and using POST instead of a GET (I know this is weird).

Also notice we use `.json` for the response instead of `.tostring`

```
WebMethodExample(): Observable<string> {

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    var content = {};

    return this._http.post("Default.aspx/WebMethodExample",
    content, {
        headers: headers
      }).map(
        (response: Response) => response.json()
    );
}
```

Comment: We're close.  If I replace the toString to text, i get the following output in the console: {"d":"Sent from WebMethodExample"} which is what is supposed to be returned.  When I try to access the property d, I get build errors...

Comment: If I do as you have shown above I get the same results as before.

Comment: what version of angular are you using?

Comment: @champ8686 see update. notice response.json now instead of tostring

Comment: I added my dependencies to the question.

Comment: Bingo.  Just had to add the .d after the json() to access the property.  Thank you so much!!